# In Angular I want to load a configuration file from assets, without promises and dynamic imports

Tags: angular, import, promise, configuration

I want to load a configuration file from assets in Angular, I don't want to use promises because it will be shown on network, I tried to add my configuration file using dynamic imports, but it will be included in build files, and I can't change it later at run time. I want a solution like reading configuration file from assets using promise, but I don't want it to be shown in network.

Here is my code for reading configuration file from assets using promises:

```
getJSON(`${this._env}.json`).subscribe(data => {
 // do some work
resolve(true);
},
getJSON(){
//return correct path to the file
}
// all above code return somthing like http.get("/assets/config/production.json").subscribe(()=>{})
```

I use this method in a service as library. This method works but shown in the network.
Here is my code for dynamic import:

```
await import('../assets/config/production').then(() => {// do something});
```

I use this in my app module as provider in a useFactory. production is a ts file. This method works but I won't be able to change it later.

I want to change my configuration file later and I don't want this file show on the network.

Comment: Isn't this what environment files are for? Or, alternatively, you could use file replacement inside angular.json?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can **not**. If you look for a .json in assets, it shown in the network: The back-end (the API) should read in server the "critical variables", not the Front-End (Angular)

Comment: @SamScholefield No, I use environment files but I want to use one build for multiple organization so adding configs to environment files won't help. I don't want to organizations see each other config file.

Comment: @Eliseo We have several organization to deploy our code and each one have different URL for API and etc... so I have to implement some hard coded config on client side, I also want to use one build for all of deployments, so I read configuration in runtime using promise but it has security issue(client see the config), so I want to change my method